# Finding a primitive function of a partial derivative of a function by integrating

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Assume I have an expression e.g. $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)=0\, \,$ :  $\, \,u=u(x,y)$.

How would I proceed (in a correct way) finding a general expression of $u(x,y)$ by integrating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = C_1 + \phi(y)
$$

and secondly

$$
u(x,y) = C_1 y + C_2 + \int_0^y\phi(\tau) d\tau + \psi(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrating once wrt $x$, you get

$$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = f_1(y) $$

where $f_1(y)$ is an arbitrary function of y only.

Then integrating this wrt $y$, you get an antiderivative of $f_1$ (and since $f_1$ is arbitrary, so is its antiderivative: call it $g(y)$) plus a "constant", which in this case means an arbitrary function of $x$. The final result is:

$$ u(x, y) = f(x) + g(y) $$

where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions.